# How to press Control + S in Chrome Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question about how we can press control + s on any page of Chrome Webdriver using C# basically i have been trying to find the solution of this from past 2 days and have found nothing and still searching. if someone help me out with it. I wud appreciate that person.
here i the code which i have written:

```
string CaptchaSrc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@class='captchaImage']")).GetAttribute("src"); 
Thread.Sleep(2000);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(CaptchaSrc); 
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + '\u0053');
Actions action = new Actions(driver); char S = '\u0053'; action.SendKeys(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control + Convert.ToString(S)).Build().Perform();
Thread.Sleep(4000); 
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\Blue\Downloads\" + captchaNumbering.ToString());
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

I have tried almost all the ways present on the StackOverFlow and even tried them all but nothing works for me. I just want to press Control + S after going to this src-URL of Image which i have scraped from the internet.

[enter link description here](http://data:image/png;base64,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)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Html Agility Pack for saving page or try this

```
.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a")
.SendKeys(Keys.Control + String.valueOf('\u0053'))
```

If picture is appaer,you can use this code for example

```
string pagehtml = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = page.Load(pagehtml);
document.save("name.html");
```

I hope this example works.I didn't check but maybe shows your way for search.

Comment: i don't understand what you have told me Html Agility Pack.

Comment: You can save any page with htmlagilitypack.

Comment: I wanna save page when there's only picture appear. And i dont know htmlagilitypack will work or not? If work then how? Kindly help me.

Comment: Please control links:
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

When picture is appear , you can save html page.I edited my answer for you.